# Why can I insert a line code before DayForecast(HashMap(it)) in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm learning the sample code about Anko at Kotlin for Android Developers (the book) at https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers

I add a line `var myMap=it` before `DayForecast(HashMap(it))`, I think that the App will crash because the definition of parseList is `parseList(parser: (Map<String, Any?>) -> T)`, I can only assign a funtion to  parseList.But the app can run correctly, why?

**My modified ForecastDb.kt**

```
override fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long) = forecastDbHelper.use {

        val dailyRequest = "${DayForecastTable.CITY_ID} = ? AND ${DayForecastTable.DATE} >= ?"
        val dailyForecast = select(DayForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple(dailyRequest, zipCode.toString(), date.toString())
                .parseList { 
                   var myMap=it
                   DayForecast(HashMap(it)) 
                 }

}
```

**ForecastDb.kt**

```
override fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long) = forecastDbHelper.use {

        val dailyRequest = "${DayForecastTable.CITY_ID} = ? AND ${DayForecastTable.DATE} >= ?"
        val dailyForecast = select(DayForecastTable.NAME)
                .whereSimple(dailyRequest, zipCode.toString(), date.toString())
                .parseList { DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }

}
```

**DatabaseExtensions.kt**

```
fun <T : Any> SelectQueryBuilder.parseList(parser: (Map<String, Any?>) -> T): List<T> =
        parseList(object : MapRowParser<T> {
            override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): T = parser(columns)
})
```

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail why you think that adding the line `var myMap = it` should cause any problem? Or have I misunderstood that you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the function is `parseList(parser: (Map<String, Any?>) -> T)`. The `(Map<String, Any?>) -> T)` as a parameter means that the `parseList` function takes as an argument a function type with a signature of a single argument (`Map<String, Any?>`) that returns a `T`.

This is an example of [*higher-order functions*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)).

In your example, you are passing in a [*lambda expression*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions):

```
.parseList { 
   var myMap=it
   DayForecast(HashMap(it)) 
}
```

In your lambda expression, you can really do anything as long as you return the type `T`. You can call multiple functions, create objects, assign variables, whatever, as long as you return the type `T` at the end.

To further illustrate this imagine we have a function that takes another function as an argument, that takes an `Int` as a parameter and returns an `Int`:

```
fun funTakingOne(function: (Int) -> Int): Int {
  return function(1)
}
```

Now, one way to call that function is to pass in a lambda expression:

```
val output = funTakingOne { 
  it + 5
}
println(output)
```

The output here is `6`.

You can also explicitly return a value from the lambda using the [*qualified return syntax*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels). Below are two identical calls:

```
funTakingOne { 
  it + 2 
}
funTakingOne { 
  return@funTakingOne it + 2
}
```

The return of this lambda expression is an `Int`. We can also do other things inside of our lambda expression, as long as the output is an `Int`:

```
funTakingOne {
  val someCalculation: Int = expensiveCalculation(it)
  val otherCalculation: Int = otherCalculation(it)
  someCalculation / otherCalculation
}
```

If you try to return anything other than `Int` here, the compiler will fail with a type mismatch:

```
// This fails to compile
funTakingOne {
  "oh no, I fail"
}
```

In your example, the signature has a [generic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) parameter (the type `T`). It is similar to the above examples, except that the function must return something of type `T`.

Here is another contrived example. A function that takes a function as an argument that has a single `String` parameter and returns something of type `T`:

```
fun <T> funReturnT(function: (String) -> T): T {
  return function("Hello World")
}
```

Calling it might look like this:

```
val output = funReturnT {
  "$it! Great day today!"
}
println(output)
```

And the output here being `Hello World! Great day today!`. The inferred type of `output` here is `String`, because our lambda expression is returning a `String` (the inferred type `T` of the function). This is the same as doing the following:

```
val output: String = funReturnT {
  "$it! Great day today!"
}
println(output)
```

If we change the expected type of the `output`, we will get a compiler failure because of type mismatch.

```
// This fails to compile
val output: Int = funReturnT {
  "$it! Great day today!"
}
println(output)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I see, lambda expression is a anonymous function, so I still pass a function to .parseList , so I can get correct result, right?

Comment: @HelloCW I think you got it!